# Create vector of sizes of the vectors inside a "2d-vector" (vector< vector<> >)?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a vector of vectors, say

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > my2dArray;
```

Now I would like to have a vector that contains the sizes of the vectors inside `my2dArray`. Manually this would look something like

```
std::vector<int> mySizes;
for (int i = 0; i < my2dArray.size(); i++ )
{
  mySizes.push_back( my2dArray[i].size() );
}
```

Is there a more "elegant" way of doing this - without manually writing a loop - by making use of some STL algorithm or the like?

Comment: What do people have against loops? I mean really, I look at the alternatives posted and I would just rather write the for loop.

Comment: this is maybe annoying to write, but I think, it is much more readable than answers you got here... maybe just rewrite it with for_each and lambda... (EDIT: john wrote almost the same... next time have to refresh first)

Comment: @john There is nothing wrong with loops. I was mostly curious as to the alternatives in this case. I'll stick with the loop here as it outperforms the other suggested solutions (within C++03), see below.

Comment: Using STL algorithms etc. effectively takes only a bit of getting used to - i find explicitly writing the code out everywhere distracts me from the actual intent.

Comment: @john: What do people have against writing loops? Well, you can write loops wrong, for one. It's hard to write `std::transform` wrong without getting a compile error. Using algorithms specifies intent (`std::transform` is a loop that transforms), while to know what a loop is doing you have to look at what it's doing. The only real downside of algorithms is the verbosity of having to write functors and such, which in C++11 is mitigated with lambdas.

Comment: @nicol And as I point out in my comment to @georg's answer: In this specific case the performance seems to be a possible downside. Using `std::transform` seems to be slower, which kind of surprises me. Maybe some of you could verify..

Comment: You could try it with a custom functor to see wether the use of the member-function-pointer is causing this. Could still be slower though, depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++03:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
std::vector<size_t> sizes(my2dArray.size());
std::transform(my2dArray.begin(), my2dArray.end(), sizes.begin(), 
               std::mem_fun_ref(&IntVec::size));
```

Comment: Would be so nice to have algorithms that can also work with whole containers, like `sizes = std::transform(my2dArray, std::mem_fun_ref(&IntVec::size));`. (Then if we could also remove that ugly mem_fun_ref, the result would be just as nice as the same in scripting languages.)

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. However, in my tests it is slower than a loop-based solution by about 15% to 20%. So I guess, I'll just stick to the loop..

Comment: @imre: You could always have wrappers that better match what you want to do.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Yeah, I know, I just wish they were part of the stdlib. These are the things that can scare away beginners from C++. "You can roll your own" is pretty different from "you have to roll your own". Anyway, this is sort of offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

About the best you're gonna get (C++11 required)

```
std::vector<int> mySizes(my2dArray.size());
auto getSize = [](const std::vector<int> & v) { return v.size(); };
std::transform(my2dArray.begin(), my2dArray.end(), mySizes.begin(), getSize);
```

It's not really a huge improvement, and if you can't use lambdas, I don't think the extra trouble would be worth it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have C++11 available at the moment so unfortunately I can't test you solution.

Comment: Well, looks like indeed I do have the auto feature already available in gcc 4.4 using the appropriate flags. I'll give it a try (can't really use these features yet, though).

Comment: No, I was wrong again. Looks like lambdas are not yet in gcc, not even using the c++0x flags..

Comment: @janitor: They have been available as of 4.5

Answer (score 0):

This works. I tried to have the sizeVec as a member of Sizes but that didn't work as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024198/stdfor-each-object-with-operator-overloaded-not-maintaining-state) question.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Sizes
{
public:
    Sizes( std::vector<int>& v ) : sizeVec( v ) {}
    void operator() ( std::vector<int>& v ) { 
        sizeVec.push_back( v.size() );  
    }
    std::vector<int>& sizeVec;
};

void outFunc (int i) {
    std::cout << " " << i;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> twodVec;

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back( 6 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 8 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );

    std::vector<int> sizeVec;
    Sizes sizes(sizeVec);
    std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), sizes );
    std::for_each( sizeVec.begin(), sizeVec.end(), outFunc );

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** : The question I asked about this has been answered by Oli Charlesworth; you can change the object to:

```
class Sizes
{
public:
    void operator() ( std::vector<int>& v ) { 
        sizeVec.push_back( v.size() );  
    }
    std::vector<int> sizeVec;
};
```

And then in main:

```
Sizes sizes;
sizes = std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), sizes );
std::for_each( sizes.sizeVec.begin(), sizes.sizeVec.end(), outFunc );
```

if you prefer. If you have boost you'll be able to use [Boost.Ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/ref.html) to make is even simpler.

**EDIT 2:** changed the functor to receive the vector by reference rather than value as suggested by Alf P Steinbach in the question I asked about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions! It works, but unfortunately this solution is considerably slower than the other proposed methods. I'd guess this is mainly due to the possible memory reallocation associated with the `push_back()`. The modified version from your 1st edit performs even worse, probably due to the additional copy operation (?).

Comment: If the mem allocation is the problem you can create the vector in sizes with the correct size as done in the other two answers