# std::for_each, object with operator() overloaded not maintaining state

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, std

In trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023539/create-vector-of-sizes-of-the-vectors-inside-a-2d-vector-vector-vector) question I came up with the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Sizes
{
public:
    void operator() ( std::vector<int> v ) { 
        sizeVec.push_back( v.size() );  
    }
    std::vector<int> sizeVec;
};

void outFunc (int i) {
    std::cout << " " << i;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> twodVec;

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back( 6 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 8 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );

    Sizes sizes;
    std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), sizes );
    std::for_each( sizes.sizeVec.begin(), sizes.sizeVec.end(), outFunc );

    return 0;
}
```

Debugging this shows Sizes::operator() being called and the size of sizeVec increasing with each call as expected. However when the second std::foreach is called the sizeVec is empty... I've created a work around involving passing a vector into Sizes but does anyone know what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::for_each` takes a functor *by value*, not *by reference*, so the original object is unaffected.  You need to do:

```
sizes = std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), sizes );
```

Comment: Even better, though, is to leave the state outside the function call, since (almost?) all of the algorithms require functors be arbitrarily copyable anyway.

Comment: @GMan: `for_each` is the exception to the rule, though.  It's explicitly designed to be used this way.  "Leaving the state outside the function call" makes re-entrancy tricky.

Comment: I know, but I mean in principle. (This is, after all, strange: pass an empty vector in, get a completely different object back. No point in that original, really.) I also don't see where reentrancy comes into play.

Comment: @GMan: I guess it depends on what you mean by "leaving the state outside of the function call"; I interpreted that to mean that `sizes` would update some global state.

Comment: Thanks Oli, I'd forgotten about this. As as extra for anyone seeing this who has boost, you can use Boost.Ref to simplify this further.

Comment: @Oli: Naw, the constructor could just take a reference to a vector, and use that. Copying no longer contains "state", since they all update the same vector.

Comment: @GMan: Yes, that makes sense.  But I'd have to ask: why bother?  Semantically, this is virtually identical to having the state inside the functor.  Either way, the observable behaviour of the functor changes over time, and the order in which it's invoked on the container is important.

Comment: I would put the vector outside the Size class (and pass it in as a reference). this has two extra benefits. 1) You do not copy the vector as the functor is passed into for_each. 2) It makes the call to for_each() more intuitive as the operator() is now const and you don;t need a separate variable (just a temporary).

Comment: @Oli: In addition to what Martin said, also consider how we'd do this in C++0x: `std::vector<int> sizeVec; sizeVec.reserve(twodVec.size()); std::for_each(twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), [&](const std::vector<int>& v){ sizeVec.push_back(v.size()); });`. It does what I suggest: take a reference to outside variables, and modify it from the functor. If we're going to write a functor, might as well emulate a lambda.

Comment: @GMan: I was just wrote that. We must be thinking in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippets shown below are quoted from your code as it was when I wrote this.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Sizes
{
public:
    void operator() ( std::vector<int> v ) {
```

`v` is passed by value, which can be pretty inefficient! Pass it by reference.

```
        sizeVec.push_back( v.size() );  
    }
    std::vector<int> sizeVec;
};

void outFunc (int i) {
    std::cout << " " << i;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

`_tmain` has never been a valid form of `main`.

This code will, at best, only compile with Microsoft's compiler.

Also, `_tmain` has no purpose even with Microsoft's compiler, except for one special case when targeting Windows 9x (not even for targeting Windows 9x in general).

Why are you writing *more* in order to render your code non-standard and ungrokkable for non-Windows programmers?

Use standard `main`.

```
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> twodVec;
```

The `>>` will probably compile with most modern compilers, due to their support for the upcoming C++0x. But in C++98/C++03 it is invalid. So, still, for portable code write `> >` (note the space).

```
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back( 6 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 8 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );
    vec.push_back( 3 );
    twodVec.push_back( vec );

    Sizes sizes;
    std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), sizes );
```

`sizes` can be freely copied here, and is in fact passed by value.

However, `std::for_each` returns a copy of the final result.

You can assign that back to `sizes`, even if it is a quite inefficient way of doing things when the functor contains a vector.

```
    std::for_each( sizes.sizeVec.begin(), sizes.sizeVec.end(), outFunc );

    return 0;
```

This final `return 0;` is not necessary with a standard `main`, since it only expresses the default return value for standard `main`.

```
}
```

Cheers & hth.

Comment: I feel that most of this should be probably written in comments, as it obscures your answer to the question itself.

Comment: @Alf: I wrote this in VS 2008 which automatically creates the _tmain and the return 0 lines, why would I change it? Good point about passing the the vector by reference though.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a couple of things differently:

```
// (1) struct rather than class for functor (as it contains no state).
struct Sizes
{
    // (2) Keep a reference to the vector
    std::vector<int>&    sizeVec;

    Sizes(std::vector<int>& sizeVec): sizeVec(sizeVec) {}

    // (3) The functor can now be const as the the state is external
    void operator() ( std::vector<int> const& v ) const
    {                              //  ^^^^^^  (4) Pass parameter by const reference
                                   //              This avoids an unnecessary copy.
        sizeVec.push_back( v.size() );  
    }
};

std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), Sizes(vec) );
                                         //    ^^^^^^^^^^  Call using temporary
                                         //                No need for a Size variable.
```

Your second for_each and outFunc() can be replaced with some standard objects:

```
std::copy(sizes.sizeVec.begin(),
          sizes.sizeVec.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
         );
```

A secondary though more obscure note, By keeping state out of the Sizes object makes it easier to convert to C++0x lambda when this arrives next year:

```
std::for_each( twodVec.begin(), twodVec.end(), Sizes(vec) );

// becomes

std::for_each( twodVec.begin(),
               twodVec.end(), 
               [&vec] ( std::vector<int> const& v ) {  vec.push_back(v.size()); }
             );
```

Comment: I am wondering as to the use of a temporary object `vec` in your call to `for_each`. The purpose of the OP was to obtain an object (a vector) that holds the sizes of the `twodVec`. With `vec` being temporary this information would be lost after the call to for_each, wouldn't it?

Comment: @janitor048: Named objects can not be temporaries (by definition). What I have done is move the vector out of the Sizes class and put within the scope of the calling class (as a named variable vec). The reason is that the third parameter to for_each() is passed by value and this causes a copy of the third value to be generated (and potentially generated in each iteration of the loop). This would cause all internal member to be copied and copying a vector can be expensive. By moving the vector out of the object I remove this cost. Also having functors with state IMO is usually a flawed

Comment: Ah, I see, I missed that `vec` has been declared within the scope of the calling class. Thanks for the clarification. Indeed I tested (I'm the OP of the post that has been refered to) the OP's version and found poor performance. I'll try yours..